# TypeScript error after update to ESNext and NodeNext

Tags: node.js, typescript

I had the previous `tsconfig.json` file:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES2018",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noEmit": true,
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "allowJs": false,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "strict": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "incremental": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "allowUnreachableCode": false,
        "allowUnusedLabels": false,
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noImplicitOverride": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
        "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"]
    }
}
```

Now, I changed it to

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ESNext",
        "module": "ESNext",
        "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
        "noEmit": true,
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "allowJs": false,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "strict": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "incremental": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "allowUnreachableCode": false,
        "allowUnusedLabels": false,
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noImplicitOverride": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
        "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"]
    }
}
```

And I also updated `package.json` file with `"type": "module"`

Now, I got issue with this code:

```
import axios from 'axios';

axios.post();
```

Property 'post' does not exist on type 'typeof import("/node_modules/.pnpm/axios@0.27.2/node_modules/axios/index")'.ts(2339)

Will work only if I do:

```
import axios from 'axios';

axios.default.post();
```

Could someone tell why, and how can I solve it? I rather not use this `default`..